# How submit that form through perl for Openwrt/LEDE

Tags: javascript, perl, openwrt, www-mechanize

I have that form

```
<form method="post" action="index.lp" name="authform" id="authform">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" onkeypress="return enter_submit(event);" />
<input name="enter" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="log in" onclick='auth()' />
```

I can submit it thanks javascript in that way

```
javascript:document.getElementById("password").value = "password";auth();
```

Now i need to write perl script to do it automatically and when it log in execute an other javascript function in page.
I'm testing it on computer and have some problem:

1) Perl need a c compiler...after i can install it on openwrt?

2) I can try 2 different ways:

**The first** and more rapid is to use WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript but i cannot install the module because i cannot install mingw (i did, in ppm-shell, install mingw and it return "ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides mingw"). Furthermore i don't see WWW::Scripter in [Perl package](https://lede-project.org/packages/index/languages---perl).
I wrote that script (can it work?):

```
  use WWW::Scripter;
  $w = new WWW::Scripter;

  $w->use_plugin('JavaScript');
  $w->get('http://url');
  $w->get('javascript:document.getElementById("password").value = "password";auth();');
  sleep (1);
  $w->get('http://url');
  $w->get('javascript: function();');
```

**The second** is to use WWW:Mechanize. How i can see output page? And how i can send command to the second page? Now with that script i get this error: "Missing base argument at D:/Program Files/Perl/lib/HTTP/Response.pm line 92.".
(can it work?)

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get( $url );

$mech->follow_link( url => 'http://url' );

$mech->submit_form(
    form_name => 'authform',
    fields    => { password  => 'password', },
    button    => 'log in'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd work with WWW::Mechanize, interpreting JS that relies on the DOM without a real browser engine is close to impossible.

`$mech->content()` will get you the raw HTML from WWW::Mechanize's last fetched page.

If you do have JavaScript-heavy pages that you need to automate and you want to use perl, look into using Selenium's WebDriver to control a "real" browser (even if it's headless like phantomjs).

As for the Error you are getting: make sure that your steps work correctly, and look at what's happening in `D:/Program Files/Perl/lib/HTTP/Response.pm` line 92, and what it does expect.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry, forgot about the OpenWRT. Mechanize should still work without it. If you run into JS, you can just fake it and make Mechanize send the correct request by itself, without interpreting JS (look at what your browser sends and replay that, basically).

Comment: i can't use selenium on openwrt/LEDE because they haven't real browser! Mechanzine shouldn't interpret javascript but just submit a form (do you read a code that i posted?) Instead WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript can interpret javascript.
What do you suggest me to do? You must to think that i need to use on openwrt/LEDE and not on other OS

Comment: I read Http header but i don't know how to reply it! i think there is md5 encryption and i don't know how to do...if you can we can use teamviewer! On line 92 i have `return $HTTP::URI_CLASS->new_abs($base, $req->uri);`

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you via Teamviewer. If it manipulates the password before transmitting it, you'll have to find out how it does so and do the same in perl. If you're working on AVM's fritz box login by any chance (they only use a password for their routers and do, or did, some md5-things in JS), use your favorite search engine, that problem has been solved before.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean! WWW:Scripter isn't a good way?

Comment: If it works, it's as good a way as any other, but I doubt that it will.

Comment: This is the first time I use perl so I asked for information! If you read the first example in that page! I think it can work...I'm wrong?http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Scripter-Plugin-JavaScript-0.009/lib/WWW/Scripter/Plugin/JavaScript.pm

Comment: It can interpret basic JavaScript, but it cannot (yet?) simulate a complete browser with a DOM and whatever else a browser brings to the table. It can't, for example, work with sites that require jQuery, see also [this discussion at perlmonks.org](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=957977).

Comment: But i need only to do the 2 operation that i posted before! I can't?

Comment: Try it, that's the only way to find out if you can! I can't tell you what else is happening on that page.

Comment: After i will try but the problem remain...when i exectue it on windows it return Can't locate WWW/Scripter.pm in @INC (you may need to install the WWW::Scripter module) (@INC contains: D:/Program Files/Perl/site/lib D:/Program Files/Perl/lib) at a2.pl line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at a2.pl line 1.

Comment: mingw is needed to install it, it's not a perl module. There are plenty of guides how to install modules on windows without ppm. Try those.